# "usbipd not found for kernel" with WSL2 (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

After `usbipd wsl list`

it returned back
`WARNING: usbipd not found for kernel 5.10.16.3-microsoft You may need to install the following packages for this specific kernel: linux-tools-5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2 linux-cloud-tools-5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2`

`You may also want to install one of the following packages to keep up to date: linux-tools-standard-WSL2 linux-cloud-tools-standard-WSL2`

I used the solutions as follows.

1. ["usbipd not found for kernel" when using USB/IP with WSL](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1384456/usbipd-not-found-for-kernel-when-using-usb-ip-with-wsl).
   It showed:
   `hwdata is already the newest version (0.333-1).`
   `linux-tools-5.4.0-77-generic is already the newest version (5.4.0-77.86).`
   `0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.`
2. https://superuser.com/questions/1694723/access-mobile-device-filesystem-from-wsl
   After installing `jmtpfs` and
   `sudo jmtpfs -o allow_other /media/android/`, it returned `No mtp devices found.`, while the Android device is shown in File Management in Windows 10 (connected via MTP).
3. https://superuser.com/questions/1686414/e-unable-to-locate-package-linux-tools-5-4-0-77-generic-on-wsl-debian-11/1688086#1688086.
   But after `sudo apt install usbip hwdata usbutils`, it returned `E: Unable to locate package usbip`.
4. https://developer.ridgerun.com/wiki/index.php/How_to_setup_and_use_USB/IP
   it returned `linux-tools-generic is already the newest version (5.4.0.139.137). 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.`
5. https://www.geekbits.io/how-to-install-usbip-tools-on-debian/
   `sudo make install` returned `make[1]: Entering directory '/mnt/d/test/libsrc' CC       libusbip_la-names.lo /bin/bash: ../libtool: No such file or directory make[1]: *** [Makefile:460: libusbip_la-names.lo] Error 127 make[1]: Leaving directory '/mnt/d/test/libsrc' make: *** [Makefile:498: install-recursive] Error 1`

And following `sudo usbipd -D`, it returned `usbipd: error while loading shared libraries: libusbip.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`.

The last but not the least, `sudo apt update` & `sudo apt upgrade` showed that all packages are up to date and upgraded.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

From my reading of the question, maybe it's necessary to link not only the client executable `usbip` but also the daemon utility `usbipd` (mind the trailing *d*)? Which means besides

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/local/bin/usbip usbip $(command -v ls /usr/lib/linux-tools/*/usbip | tail -n1) 20
```

one may need

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/local/bin/usbipd usbipd $(command -v ls /usr/lib/linux-tools/*/usbipd | tail -n1) 20
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.  Two things - First, thanks for noticing that this was `usbipd` (not `usbip` as I was thinking).  Second, under WSL, the `usbipd` is provided by the host (Windows) rather than Ubuntu, so attempting to use the Ubuntu one won't work (and is likely the root problem).  I'll revise my answer, but I do appreciate the second look at it!

Comment: I find this a bit weird - I upvoted even though the answer is *wrong*, but it *was helpful* ;-)

Comment: I instantly agree :D Thx

Answer (score 0):

<sub>*Thanks to @Nielo for [pointing out](https://askubuntu.com/a/1457200/1165986) that you are attempting to run `usbipd` (not `uspip`, as I originally thought).*</sub>

Under WSL:

- The USB/IP daemon (`usbipd.exe`) is run under *Windows*, since it's Windows that is *sharing* (via `usbipd bind`) the device.
- The USB/IP client (`usbip`) is what you should be running under *Ubuntu*, to connect to the device that was shared Windows daemon.

So from *PowerShell* in Windows, try running `usbipd list` (or `usbipd wsl list`)

Note:  To run `usbipd bind`, you'll need to be in an Admin PowerShell.

Keep in mind that, as long as you are trying to connect a device to your default distribution, and you've set up the `usbip` command in Ubuntu as mentioned in [my answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1406206/1165986), *all* of the `usbipd` commands can be run from an admin PowerShell.

For instance:

```
usbipd wsl list
# Identify BUSID of device to attach
usbipd wsl attach --busid <busid>
```

This does two things:

- Binds/shares the device from Windows through the USB/IP daemon
- Sends the appropriate command *to* Ubuntu to attach to the device.